# Posting IDs to REST API

Tags: rest

I am designing a REST API for inserting a record to the "solutions" table. A "solution" has a solverID, problemID. I have two different designs in mind:

```
POST /solutions
```

and passing the solverID and problemID in JSON with the content of the solution. Or putting the solverID and problemID in the URI:

```
POST /users/:solver_id/problems/:problem_id/solutions
```

Which design is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good practice to define your resources in a consistent hierarchy, so that they are easily understandable and predictable.

Let's say this is the URL to retrieve a  question -

```
GET     /users/{solverId}/problems/{problemId}
```

It clearly conveys that the problem belongs to the {solverId}.

The following URL would clearly show that the we are retrieving all solutions for problems solved by {solverId}

```
GET     /users/{solverId}/problems/{problemId}/solutions
```

To create a new solution for the {problemId}, you would do a post on

```
POST     /users/{solverId}/problems/{problemId}/solutions
```

To retrieve a particular solution you would do a get on

```
GET     /users/{solverId}/problems/{problemId}/solutions/{solutionId}
```

When to use Ids in path vs query ?

If an ID is definitely required to identify a resource, use it in the path. In the above scenario, since all three Ids are required to uniquely identify a solution, all of them should be in the path.

Let's say you want to retrieve a solution that was given in a particular date range, you would use the following

```
GET     /users/{solverId}/problems/{problemId}/solutions?startDate={}&endDate={}
```

Here startDate and endDate cannot uniquely identify a resource, they are just  parameters that are being used to filter the results.

Comment: Thanks. The criteria to decide using ids in path vs query seem to be a good one. However, in my case, a user could never get other users' resources. So the {solverId} is always the current user's Id, otherwise the server will reject it. In such case, is it necessary to put a {solverId} in the path?

Comment: Also, if the {solutionId} is globally unique, wouldn't it be better to use `GET /solutions/{solutionId}` to get a solution?

Comment: For the first question regarding {solverId} - REST services are supposed to be stateless, so the service wouldn't know what the current user's id is. So, you'll have to somehow convey it to the service. Putting {solverId} it in the path is one way of conveying it.

Comment: Regarding {solutionId} - Yes, if the {solutionId} is unique, you could go with 'solutions/{solutionId}' as the path. But, if you want your URLs to convey a meaningful hierarchy where users will be able to guess what a URL exactly means, you could go with "/users/{solverId}/problems/{problemId}/solutions/{solutionId}". This longer URL conveys that the solution they are looking at is for a problem with {problemId}. They could now easily look at the problem by using the URL "/users/{solverId}/problems/{problemId}". I think there is no hard and fast rule on what approach you use.

Answer (score 1):

Go with the first one. I would keep your urls as clean and simple as you can. Here are some other examples off the top my head. Not sure on your entire structure.

```
POST /solutions

GET /solutions?solverid=123  //query solutions by user

GET /users/555/problems      // problems for a given user
GET /users/555/solutions     // solutions for a given user

GET /problems/987/solutions  // solutions for a given problem
```

Comment: I am actually not clear when an ID should be in the route, when it should be in the query string/request body. For example, why not: `GET /problems/987` and `GET /problems?user_id=555`?

Comment: Good point. I work with a framework that accepts both. If its the primary key or unique I will use it in the path. If its more like a search to query then I will put it in the query string.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a scheme: including user ID in the route only when authentication is not needed for the route, otherwise, the user ID can be figured out from the authentication information, and the above route becomes:

```
POST /problems/:problem_id/solutions
```